# MVC model edit not saving

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework

This is related to and sort of follows from [this other question I had previously posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32913104/mvc-model-that-includes-property-of-a-different-model)...

I added a new property to the Site model, so this is what that looks like now:

```
SiteID() As Integer
Name() As String
Latitude() As Double
Longitude() As Double
User() As ApplicationUser
```

If you look at the Devices Controller in my Answer on that question - Creating a Device works fine and the Site selected is properly saved for the Device.

When I EDIT a Device, however, and change the selected Site, that change is not getting saved.

In an earlier attempt to fix this, I added a line to remove the Site from the Device, so this is what the Edit Post looks like now:

```
    Async Function Edit(<Bind(Include:="DeviceID,Make,Model,Serial")> ByVal device As Device) As Task(Of ActionResult)
        If ModelState.IsValid Then
            'Because Site is selected in a DropDownFor which only passes the ID integer, need to set the device's site property accordingly
            'Note that with Site being a Navigation property, it looks like it doesn't get saved the way you would think...but it all works
            ModelState.Remove("Site")
            Dim thisSite As Integer = CInt(Request.Form.Get("Site.SiteID"))
            device.Site = (From site In db.Sites Where site.SiteID = thisSite Select site).FirstOrDefault()
            db.Entry(device).State = EntityState.Modified
            Await db.SaveChangesAsync()
            Return RedirectToAction("Index")
        End If
        Return View(device)
    End Function
```

That did not do it though.  When I step through the code, the device's Site does get set properly, so it looks like it's fine, but then the Index Get is getting the old value for the Device's Site.

Why is this not saving properly?

Note that changing other properties of the Device in Edit does work fine.  Thank you!

Comment: `State = EntityState.Modified` only affects scalar properties. Set `SiteID` in stead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what Gert Arnold said was posted as an answer, I'd have marked that as accepted.  I did not know this was the case!  (and it would be nice if it actually did).  But anyway, here's the details on what I ended up doing:

I did have to add a property to the Device model to hold SiteID - I called it "SiteNum".

In the Create and Edit Posts, I simply set SiteNum according to the site selected in the drop down.

Because I want to display the name of the site associated with the device, in the Gets (except for Create) I am setting device.Site using the SiteNum, updating the tables, and then including Site in the model passed to the View.

As an example of this, here is now my Index in the Controller:

```
' GET: Devices
Async Function Index() As Task(Of ActionResult)
    'Have to set device's Site here in case user selected a different Site in Edit (which only updates scalar properties)
    Dim sitesList = db.Sites.Include("User").ToList
    'Can't call db.Sites within the For Each because it gives error about it already being open
    For Each item In db.Devices
        item.Site = sitesList.Where(Function(x) x.SiteID = item.SiteNum).FirstOrDefault()
        db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified
    Next
    'Then have to update the database with the sites for the devices so the rest of this stuff will work
    Await db.SaveChangesAsync()
    Dim curUserID = User.Identity.GetUserId()
    'Need to have this include Site so that it will pull in that data in order to reference site name in the View
    '(doing this is called Eager Loading).  Only get devices for sites associated with logged in user.
    Dim devices = db.Devices.Include("Site").Where(Function(x) x.Site.User.Id = curUserID).ToListAsync()
    Return View(Await devices)
End Function
```

Thank you!